# Java - Access Object's Array List through HashMap (Key is object)

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator, hashmap

I am trying to loop through a HashMap, then for each key I want to access the object (Shipment) that is associated to the key and access my array list for further analysis purposes. Each object/key in HashMap has the same array list (metricList). I cannot seem to access it, though I have checked the private/public thing. Can someone point me in the right direction?

I think I need to maybe get the class of my object and then use the method "getList"... I tried with no luck.

This is a sample of the code (removed irrelevant parts) if it helps:

This is my object:

```
public class Shipment{

    //Members of shipment
    private final String shipment;
    public Date creationDate;
    public int creationTiming;
    public int processingTiming;
    public ArrayList<Integer> metricList;

    public void createArrayList() {
        // create list 
        metricList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        // add metric to list
        metricList.add(creationTiming);
        metricList.add(processingTiming);
   }

    public ArrayList<Integer> getList() {
       return metricList;
   }
}
```

This is the class where I create a hashMap and run through different analysis:

```
public class AnalysisMain {

    public static Map<String, Shipment> shipMap = new HashMap();

    public static void main(String[] args) {     
        try {
        ... // Different calls to analysis
        }
        catch {}  
    }
}
```

This is where the issue occurs (it does not recognize that I already have a "metricList", asking if I want to create local variable)

```
public class Metric_Analysis{
    public static void analyze() throws Exception{

        ResultSet rs;

            try {
                rs = getSQL("SELECT * FROM TEST_METRICS"); 
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                //Pass the error
                throw new java.lang.Exception("DB Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Shipment>> iterator = shipMap.entrySet().iterator();
            while(iterator.hasNext()){

                   Iterator<String> metricIterator = metricList.iterator();

                   //Above is the Array List I want to access and loop through
                   //I will then perform certain checked against other values on a table...

                    while (metricIterator.hasNext()) {
                    //I will perform certain things here
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: `metricList` is not known in `Metric_Analysis`, you should get it first.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I tried to put "getList();" after "while(iterator.hasNext())" but it is still not working asking if I want to create the method when it is already created in my Shipment class... :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the List out of your Shipment.
You can access the object from the iterator with: iterator.next();
This will also set the pointer to the next Entry in your List/Map.

Change your code:

```
  Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Shipment>> iterator = shipMap.entrySet().iterator();
            while(iterator.hasNext()){

                   // Get the Entry from your Map and get the value from the Entry
                   Entry<String, Shipment> entry = iterator.next();
                   List<Integer> metricList = entry.getValue().getList();

                   Iterator<String> metricIterator = metricList.iterator();

                   //Above is the Array List I want to access and loop through
                   //I will then perform certain checked against other values on a table...

                    while (metricIterator.hasNext()) {
                    //I will perform certain things here
                    }
            }
```